# redirect to the particulate link from dropdown list by using loop

Tags: javascript, html

please help me to pass parameters to do this operation ...
i want to pass 1 or more functions to another with parameters .

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function a(a)
        {
            return a;
        }
        function b(b)
        {
            return b;
        }
        function add(a,b)
        {
            a();
            b();
            var c = a+b;
            document.write("this is tour ans:-"+c);
        }
      </script>

   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <input type="button" onclick="add(10,20)" value="click me.">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your Dropdown in HTML ?

Comment: Title of the question and the body are totally different.... Please use the correct title or reflect the proper question in body

Comment: oops ...
its a huge mistake ...
**sorry** for this ...
actually m new on this ...
so i made a mistake

Comment: So where is the change!! When will u reflect it??? By the way you can go through this article on [Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Answer (score 0):

No redirection or dropdown in your question, but i think you have problem displaying result, so i Modified your code, tested and works 100%

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(a)
    {
        return a;
    }
    function b(b)
    {
        return b;
    }
    function add(one,two)
    {
        var c = a(one)+b(two);
        document.write("this is tour ans:-"+c);
    }
</script>
```